# meteor bundled application redirects to ssl

Tags: meteor

My meteor project gets bundled with a script and run with forever. Until now, the process used to work fine but for my last project it does not work.

I setup a clean server with no httpd process running to be sure there is no interference.

there are no errors but when I go to my application on `http://dev.sertal.ch:4020` I get redirected to `https://dev.sertal.ch`

This is the bundle script:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  cd /root/projects/tablet-reporting/app
  git pull

  rm -Rf /opt/sertal/tablet-reporting-test
  rm -f /opt/sertal/tablet-reporting-test.tgz

  meteor bundle /opt/sertal/tablet-reporting-test.tgz
  cd /opt/sertal
  tar -xvzf tablet-reporting-test.tgz
  mv bundle tablet-reporting-test

  cd /opt/sertal/tablet-reporting-test/programs/server/node_modules
  rm -Rf fibers
  npm install fibers
```

this is how the app is started:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/tablet-reporting-test" PORT=4020 ROOT_URL="http://dev.sertal.ch:4020" node tablet-reporting-test/main.js
```

it says

```
LISTENING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have the `force-ssl` package installed.

```
meteor remove force-ssl
```

Then rebundle and redeploy. Please let know if it doesn't work it might be some proxy thing instead.